# Problems in R for OSX with the download.file function

Tags: r, macos

OK, so this is an R problem specific to OSX.

I'm trying to download XML data through an API. The following code works just fine on a PC, but not on a Mac. I have rotated through all the "methods" (curl, etc.) to no avail. Any thoughts?

```
tempx <- "temp.xml"
url <- "http://usaspending.gov/fpds/fpds.php?detail=b&fiscal_year=2012&maj_agency_cat=97&max_records=10&sortby=d&records_from=1"

download.file(url, tempx, method="auto")
```

ETA: Here's my error:

```
trying URL 'http://usaspending.gov/fpds/fpds.php?detail=b&fiscal_year=2012&maj_agency_cat=97&max_records=10&sortby=d&records_from=1'
Error in download.file(url, tempx, method = "auto") : 
  cannot open URL 'http://usaspending.gov/fpds/fpds.php?detail=b&fiscal_year=2012&maj_agency_cat=97&max_records=10&sortby=d&records_from=1'
```

Comment: What do you get as error?

Comment: check out the package XML for parsing XML and RCurl for curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine with `httr`:

```
library(httr)
url <- "http://usaspending.gov/fpds/fpds.php?detail=b&fiscal_year=2012&maj_agency_cat=97&max_records=10&sortby=d&records_from=1"
GET(url)
```

because it automatically handles the redirects:

```
GET(url)$url
# [1] "http://usaspending.gov/api/fpds_api_basic.php?fiscal_year=2012&maj_contracting_agency=97%2A&Contracts=c&sortby=SIGNED_DATE%2Basc&records_from=0&max_records=10&sortby=SIGNED_DATE+asc"
```

Comment: And then how do I extract the XML text from the result?

Comment: Never mind! Seems xmlTreeParse works just fine on the object that GET is assigned to. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much an answer as a comment wth formatting. I'm also an OSX user and have the same problem with your code as well as problems with my efforts at a solution:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
gotten <- getURL("http://usaspending.gov/fpds/fpds.php?detail=b&fiscal_year=2012&maj_agency_cat=97&max_records=10&sortby=d&records_from=1")

> gotten
[1] "\n"


> gotten2 <- getURLContent("http://usaspending.gov/fpds/fpds.php?detail=b&fiscal_year=2012&maj_agency_cat=97&max_records=10&sortby=d&records_from=1")
> 
> gotten2
[1] "\n"
attr(,"Content-Type")

"text/xml"
```

So I think some sort of response occurs but that the initial response is very short and the code is not ready to accept what comes afterwards.